# How to test using a variety of build options with AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS CodeBuild as a replacement for [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org). (Travis-CI was just too slow for our needs.) I would like to have CodeBuild test a variety of different configurations:

- static vs shared libraries
- gnu vs llvm compilers
- debug vs release optimizations

I have a very simple `buildspec.yml` file that works well, but it doesn't seem to be able to generate a matrix of options like I can do on Travis-CI.

I could create a variety of `buildspec.yml` files with each one doing something a little differently, but that quickly gets out of hand with the different options that need to be considered.

> What is the right/best way to do this with AWS CodeBuild?

Answer (score -1):

I am from the AWS CodeBuild team. Thanks for your feedback and feature request. We'll pass this to our product management team to consider for future roadmap.

As you said, one option would be creating multiple buildspec.yml files and using overriding per build based on the desired build config.

Alternatively, you could have a single buildspec.yml that executes different build scripts based on an environment variable. For example you could have an environment variable called BUILD_CONFIG whose value will be read by your build script to determine which build configuration to use.

Environment variables can be overriden per build. Use the environmentVariablesOverride field in StartBuild: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_StartBuild.html#CodeBuild-StartBuild-request-environmentVariablesOverride

Comment: I presume that the different build scripts are called in the `build` phase and the `commands` are simply to call another bash script (for example).

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on what this `StartBuild` is? I'm not sure where I can use this from my `buildspec.yml` file.